# Сортировка таблицы без перезагрузки с помощью jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так чтобы при нажатии "на одну кнопку из них" сортировала по kil DESC при повторной  нажатии ASC ?

Я знаю как но мне нужно БЕЗ ПЕРЕЗАГРУЗКИ СТРАНИЦЫ то есть через jquary как это сделать? заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы большой поклонник jQuery, то можете воспользоваться любым решением, найденным по запросу [google://jquery+sortable+table](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+sortable+table). Например, [TableSorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/):

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter( {sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]]} ); 
    } 
);
```

Comment: Спасибо что познакомил с таким отличным плагином всё сделал работает на ура.